# Copy the contents of one array into another within a pointer to a structure | C

Tags: c, struct, memory-management

I have the following structure:

```
struct NumArray {
    size_t size;
    int* data;
};
```

Then, I wrote this function to build a "NumArray" from a common array:

```
struct NumArray* CreateNumArray(const int* nums, const size_t size) {
    struct NumArray* numarray = malloc(sizeof(struct NumArray));

    if (numarray == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    numarray->data = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    if (numarray->data == NULL) {
        free(numarray);
        return NULL;
    }

    numarray->size = size;
    memcpy(numarray->data, nums, size);

    return numarray;
}
```

But when I tested it, it seems that I have copied the information wrongly:

```
int main(void) {
    int sample[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    struct NumArray* arr = CreateNumArray(sample, sizeof(sample) / sizeof(sample[0]));

    if (arr == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < arr->size; ++idx) {
        printf("%d ", arr->data[idx]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 476 338297168 476
```

Could someone help me find the error?

NOTE: I'm using gcc 11.2.0

Comment: `memcpy(numarray->data, nums, size);` --> `memcpy(numarray->data, nums, size * sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
memcpy(numarray->data, nums, size);
```

it must be

```
memcpy(numarray->data, nums, size * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what was missing, I don't know how I could ignore it.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, what is your point in `const`-qualifying the `size` parameter of `CreateNumArray`?